How to get a study's complete list of hyper parameters and their importance in Optuna?
I'm using Optuna to find the best values for training my machine learning model. Using Optuna dashboard I can see a chart showing a list of my hyper parameters and their importance. It's just the list shows only 9 of my hyper parameter while I have over 20. Reading the documentation, I can also use Python and get the same info and it comes with 3 different algorithms to calculate the importance:
importances = optuna.importance.get_param_importances(study,
                                                      evaluator=FanovaImportanceEvaluator(),
                                                      normalize=True)

importances = optuna.importance.get_param_importances(study,
                                                      evaluator=MeanDecreaseImpurityImportanceEvaluator(),
                                                      normalize=True)

importances = optuna.importance.get_param_importances(study,
                                                      evaluator=PedAnovaImportanceEvaluator(),
                                                      normalize=True)

But all these approaches also give me only the 9 most important hyper parameters. Is there a way to ask for all my hyper parameters and their importance?
